# jquery DataTable Server Side Paging Next Button working only on the first page

Tags: jquery, datatables, paging

I have used jquery data-table with server side paging and its works fine.

But when i click on "Next" button in paging footer, its works only on first page. From second page on-wards nothing happens if i click on "Next" button.

```
 gDataTable = $(table_id).DataTable({
    "autoWidth": false,
    "iDisplayLength":  getCookieValue("gridLength"),
    "serverSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": gSvcUrl + qstr + "&rndm=" + Math.random(),
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings)
    {
        sSource += "&aaSorting=" + oSettings.aaSorting;
        sSource += "&iDisplayStart=" + aoData[3].value;
        var searchEscaped = escape(oSettings.oPreviousSearch.sSearch);
        sSource += "&sSearch=" + searchEscaped;
        sSource += "&DisplayLength=" + oSettings._iDisplayLength;
        var tloc = gSvcUrl + qstr;
        var param = (params == null) ? null : JSON.stringify(params);

        $("#iframeloading").show();
        var req_start = new Date();
        var req_end;

        oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "POST",
            "url": sSource,
            "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            "data": param,
            "success": function (data, textStatus, request, d) {
             },
             error: function (xhr, textStatus) {

                $("#iframeloading").hide();
                if (callType) {
                    CreateOfflineCallStructure(qstr, params, callType, qid);
                }
                else {
                    ProcessErrorInfo(xhr);
                }
            }
        });
```

Please help me

Comment: Show your response please, generally this problem is for JSON response!

Comment: Sample Response is like bellow: {"response_code":"0","response_type":0,"message":null,"gpdata1":[["0","000000003","",
"A aaa Supply Company","USA","Distributor","D",""," ","","","","adfasfasf",
"United States","","","","21-Dec-2015","33","21-Dec-2015","33"],["1","000000021","",
"C Andersen Electric Supply Co. Inc.","USA","Distributor","D",""," ","","","",
"afdaf","United States","","","","21-Dec-2015","33","21-Dec-2015","33"]
]]

Comment: When you use `serverSide:true` , you should return `{
    "draw": 1,
    "recordsTotal": 57,
    "recordsFiltered": 57,
    "data": [ ......]}` this format for drawn DataTables. https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: I have updated my code according to above format, but still same result